# How to disable the "Screen is pinned" ScrollView?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sony-xperia-z5

Everytime I pin an app I get a "Screen is pinned" green [ScrollView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/res/layout/screen_pinning_instructions.xml) and have to tap the "Got it" button.
At first, I thought it was just some kind of "getting started" thing, but after a few months it's still showing up every single time.
Since I'm pretty sure I "Got it", is there a way to disable this warning/info ?

Here's a screenshot of the ScrollView.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked here for other similar questions? Here is a [query](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=disable+overlay+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) to other questions on this non-unique topic. All have at least one answer submitted; some actually with accepted answers. Please review them, and edit your question to show how they are inappropriate to resolving your issue.

Comment: Yes I did and found nothing related to my issue.

Comment: @noodlesup - you cannot disable that directly. May be the answer below can do that. I thought nobody in this world uses screen pinning feature ;)

Answer (score -1):

What device are you using? You may (or may not) be able to remove this message via your stock settings.

In any case, to remove this message you'll need **root** access and an app called [EhancedToast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.defim.apk.enhancedtoast).

---

This will allow you to select the toast messages that you don't want to show up. For example: ***Screen Pinned,*** ***Screen Unpinned*** and messages of the sort.

**Requirements For EnhancedToast Method**

1. Xposed Framework (one that's compatible with your device, obviously).
2. Install the EnhancedToast Xposed Module.

---

**From your phone (using a Terminal Emulator app - Root Required)**

```
su
appops set android TOAST_WINDOW deny
```

**From PC (adb required) but no root needed**

```
adb shell appops set android TOAST_WINDOW deny
```

---

Please let me know if these methods work(ed) for you and good luck!

[Source](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/144146/205602)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed guide ! I'm using an Xperia Z5 Compact.  So there's  no other way than rooting the phone ? It seems pretty overkill for a notification :(

Comment: Nice copy and pasta from a previous question.

Comment: @Ben Baltz, please stay on topic and stick to the topic at hand. Constructive answers and sources help best. Also, pasta is a food.

Comment: Well you could at least give credit to the original poster rather than claiming this as your answer. Original: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/144146/205602

Comment: Technically, I never claimed it as mine. People who post questions are always suggested, strongly, to do research before posting a new thread. In any case, fair point, regardless. Since you've submitted the link here, that was helpful too. Thank you!

Comment: Anyhow, this doesn't answer the question. This technique suppresses the white toast message that pops up, but does nothing about the ugly turquoise "screen is pinned, got it" message this question is talking about.